# Delay Excluded JavaScript Files adsense

Tags: javascript, adsense

if you don't leave adsense in Excluded JavaScript Files, then you will face ads loading problem. and if you include then it will effect website performance . other issues will start coming.check the urls this url https://www.digitalkhabar.in/new-good-morning-images-with-quotes/ at https://pagespeed.web.dev/.

Not satisfy with wp rocket plugin response.

Comment: [partytown](https://partytown.builder.io/) may help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my question is related to the loading problem of adsense. when you Excluded JavaScript Files like adsense under delay load javascript differed of wp rocket plugin . loading problem solves but it effects the performance of the page.